# How to set Server Side Git Hook to give permission in master branch to certain user names?

Tags: server, git

I have a git server. Not gitlab or something similar, bare git server. I wanted to create git hook to decline push on master branch for certain users. I tried to do that with below one.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" == refs/heads/master ];
then
    CEMAIL=$(git log -1 --format=format:%ce HEAD)

    echo $CEMAIL

    if [ "$CEMAIL" != fahad@domain.com ] && [ "$CEMAIL" != jake@domain.com ];
    then
        echo "-----------------------------------------------------"
        echo "WARNING: You are not allowed to Push in MASTER branch !"
        echo "-----------------------------------------------------"
        exit 1
    fi
fi
```

Users without above email should not be able to push on master branch. But It is not working as expected. Can you guys please guide me about it ?

**UPDATE:** When i (fahad@domain.com) it will allow me to push to the branch. And then if i ask someone else to push to the branch other than me and jake, then it allows too. It picks the last users email.

Comment: What do you mean it's not working as expected? What does it do that you don't expect it to do?

Comment: @dma1324 , I have updated the question......